# Problem while building a PyQt script with py2exe (QtCore)

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I'm trying to make a simple hello-world executable python gui app in windows using pyqt. So I've made the `pyqt.py` file

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QPushButton("Hello World", None)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

I tried to use py2exe with the following `setup.py` script:

```
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

setup( console=[{"script": "pyqt.py"}] )
```

(I had the `No module named sip` error first, but it's solved thanks to the `Py2exeAndPyQt` page).

Now I have the executable and when i try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqt.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

How can I fix it? TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this, you don't need import *.

```
py2exe_opciones = {'py2exe': {"includes":["sip"]}}
script = [{"script":"pyqt.py"}]

setup(windows=script,options=py2exe_opciones)
```

And now will the program should work. I had the same error.

[Here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt) can read more.

Answer (score 2):

Add `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` to pyqt.py.

I'm not sure why it wasn't auto-included, but I think it has something to do with QtCore only being used by QtGui, which is a C++ lib...  Like, py2exe only auto-detects python dependencies...  So you have to import it manually.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob

SETUP_DICT = {
    'windows': [{
        'script': 'main.py',
    }],

    'zipfile': 'lib/library.zip',

    'data_files': (
        ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp100.dll')),
        ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcr100.dll')),
    ),

    'options': {
        'py2exe': {
            'bundle_files': 3,
            'includes': ['sip', 'PyQt4.QtCore'],
        },
    }
}

setup(**SETUP_DICT)
```